# I am getting Ajax I/O error while clicking on any button, drop down in my script

Tags: ajax, authentication, selenium-webdriver, ioerror

The web application on which I am working has an authentication mechanism. To access this I need to provide some user id and pwd. After entering credentials when I try to select any drop down value or try to navigate to another page using pagination, getting Ajax I/O error with error code 502. Its not reproducible manually. Only via selenium script I am getting this error.

I have tried alert method, but its not useful. On this Ajax alert pop up I am getting only OK option on which if I tried to click its not selecting the desired value.

I want to select value from the drop down without any Ajax error.

Comment: 'try {
    addAnotherParagraphbutton.click();
 } catch (UnhandledAlertException f) {
 try {
     Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        System.out.println("Alert data: " + alertText);
        alert.accept();
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
}'

Comment: You can [edit] your question and post code there (see [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))